# Cannot build specflow from source

Tags: visual-studio-2010, specflow

I downloaded specflow's source from here: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow

I tried to build this source with VS2010 but, "Vs2010Integration" project couldn't be loaded for some reason.
Does anyone knows what I'm missing?
Some plugins, maybe wrong VS, maybe some configurations to be set?

regards,

Vajda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have look at:

https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Building-SpecFlow

All the needed infrastructure for building SpecFlow from source should be listed there.